# What other combinations with ion disrupters are there?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I know that it is possible to mix ion disruptors and cluster flack arrays in the same turret to create ionized flak because the ion charges will arc between the flak fragments.

Is it possible to do this with ammo based weapons as well?  Like ionized energy bolt chainguns.

What about on weapons not fired from the ship (will it arc if two ships work together, one with flak one with IDs?)

Finally, is ionized fire possible with IDs + Plasma Burst Generators because that would be awesome.

Comment: That's the first I've heard of ionized flak. Gotta try that when I pick up X3 again.

Comment: Likewise, going to have to remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ion disruptors + CFA is the only combo that will work. This is because IonD jumps from object to object as you know very well by now. The only Weapon/Ammo that actually emits multiple shards per round is the CFA.

The FAA (Flak Artillery Array) shoots out a single flak payload which explodes later, so do other ammo based weapons like the EBC(Energy Bolt Chaingun). So this leaves us with Beam/Plasma weapons that do not emit physical objects, so they can be discounted for this purpose.

So IonD only combines with CFA for now and not any other weapon.